# ASP.NET Core HostedService is trying to access database before it's created

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I'm developing an asp.net project using .NET 5.0; in this project i use Entity Framework, code first, with a sql lite file database.

In `startup.cs` file i use the following code to create and update db schema programmatically:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DataContext dataContext)
{
    // migrate any database changes on startup (includes initial db creation)
    dataContext.Database.Migrate();

    ...
}
```

Then i have a service that i use to clean old data from some tables of database. It cleans them on startup and periodically:

```cs
public class TimedDbCleanerService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{

    ...
}
```

With those functions:

```cs
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
        TimeSpan.FromHours(_dbCleanerSettings.Hours));

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private void DoWork(object state)
{
    // create scoped dbcontext
    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();

        // check and remove stuff

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Registered with this line of code in `startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddHostedService<TimedDbCleanerService>();
```

The problem here is that if the database file doesn't exist before executing the project, the cleaner service tries to access a table of database that doesn't exist yet.

Using debugger i can see that the `Database.Migrate()` is called before the service access the database, but the migration seems to be an async task that takes time to be completed.

There's a way to wait to migration to fully execute its job, before creating and starting the cleaner service?

Comment: You can use a global static cancellationtoken and wait for it to be set in the background service. then when the migration ends, you set the token, and background service continues execution.

Comment: @abdusco seems a good solution, can you please provide an example as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better alternative could be to perform the migrations before you start the app, which would simplify things quite a bit. No need for synchronization between threads.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
        db.Database.Migrate();
    }
    
    // database migration is completed
    
    host.Run();
}
```

Since this is done before the background service starts running, there's no risk of a race condition.

Now the background service becomes even simpler:

```cs
class CleanerService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public CleanerService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await PerformCleanup();
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(1), stoppingToken);
            await PerformCleanup();
        }
    }

    private async Task PerformCleanup()
    {
        using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
        // ... clean things up
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class to orchestrate the migration. This will perform the migration and help others wait for the completion using a `SemaphoreSlim`.

Inside this class we inject the `DbContext` and run the migration, then let the threads waiting for the migration continue execution.

```cs
public class DatabaseMigrator
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _migrationEvent = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

    public DatabaseMigrator(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void Migrate()
    {
        _dbContext.Database.Migrate();
        _migrationEvent.Release(1);
    }

    public Task WaitForMigrationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return _migrationEvent.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Register this class to DI:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<DatabaseMigrator>();
```

In your `Main` function or `Startup.Configure`, inject this function and run the migration:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DatabaseMigrator databaseMigrator)
{
    databaseMigrator.Migrate();
    // ...
}
```

In the background service, we don't inject the migrator, because it depends on scoped services like `DbContext`. Instead, we resolve one from a scope we create, wait for the migration to complete.

```cs
class CleanerService : BackgroundService
{
    private IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public CleanerService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var migrator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseMigrator>();
            await migrator.WaitForMigrationAsync(stoppingToken);
        }

        await PerformCleanup();
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(1), stoppingToken);
            await PerformCleanup();
        }
    }

    private async Task PerformCleanup()
    {
        using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
        // ... clean things up
    }
}
```

---

One small point: Instead of using a `Timer` in an async context that forces you to use `void`, which bring a horde of problems when working async, you can call `Task.Delay` in a loop, which will release the thread to threadpool to let it execute other tasks while waiting:

```cs
await PerformCleanup();
while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(1), stoppingToken);
    await PerformCleanup();
}
```

Comment: How come you posted two answers? Is it to (a) answer the actual question and, then, (b) provide an answer to a better question not having been asked (but being recommended to)?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Yes, basically. In this answer, I provided a solution, but realized what OP actually wants to do and gave another & simpler solution. Since both solutions are quite unrelated in their scope & approach, I submitted the answers separately.